# URL. Retrive only script name and query string

Tags: php, url

FULL URL: `http://www.somepage.com/admin/index.php?do=manageNews&search=1&sort=title&order=ASC`

How to retrieve only this part: `index.php?do=manageNews&search=1&sort=title&order=ASC`

Comment: [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) ought to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of the [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) functions as follows:

```
$url = 'http://www.somepage.com/admin/index.php?do=manageNews&search=1&sort=title&order=ASC';

# retrieve index.php file name using pathinfo() and parse_url()
$file = pathinfo(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), PATHINFO_BASENAME);

# retrive query string using parse_url()
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);

# combine file name and query string.
if (strlen($query)>0) {
    $file .= '?' . $query;
}

echo "$file\n"; # index.php?do=manageNews&search=1&sort=title&order=ASC
```